# Is there a limit on how many posts you can edit?

Tags: support, editing

Is there a limit on how many times you can edit? Sometimes the edit button doesn't come up but it comes up after another one of my edits is accepted. Is there a limit on how many edits can be pending review at a time?

Comment: Keep in mind when you make a lot of edits in a rapid manner, if they get approved, the edited posts get bumped to the top of the Active queue and can saturate the queue.  I was once contacted by moderators to watch my edits for two reasons: 1. was because of this active queue reason, and 2. was because the edits were rather superficial (I'll admit I was going for a badge and making some rather poor edits).  I was past 2k rep at the time, so my edits were applied immediately, saturating the active queue very fast.  I've noticed that a few of your edits recently have been superficial.

Comment: Try to avoid making these small edits for the above reasons.  Too many rejected edits will land you a temporary edit ban.

Comment: Just saw this, ^^ agreed with Timmy, I find myself rejected quite a few of your edits as they seem unimportant, irrelevant, superficial or otherwise unnecessary. Just think before you edit, "does this *really* improve the question or answer?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes. There is a limit of 5 suggested edits which can be pending for a single user.**

For more information, see *[Why is the edit button disabled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81681/351462)*